# How to publish custom artifacts to Nexus?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two artifacts which I need to `publish` to Nexus. The location is as follows:

- `myproject/db/target/db-deploy.zip` for db deployment
- `myproject/target/service.jar` executable service

I have already defined `credentials` and `publishTo` in `build.sbt`.

```
publishTo := Some("Sonatype Snapshots Nexus" at "http://whatever/nexus/")
```

It works fine when I start the `publish` task.

How can I code it in `build.sbt` if I want to `publish` those 2 artifacts? I also tried `addArtifact`, but it fails on compilation.

Comment: `sbt --version`, please. `cat project/build.properties`, too. Are you using a multi-module build with `myproject` being the top-level module with `db` as a submodule? What happens when you execute `publish` task from `myproject` directory? It's supposed to traverse the other subprojects and execute `publish` for each. Show the build definition - `*.sbt` + `project/*.scala` files.

Comment: I am using sbt 0.13.0, build.proerpties I configured is sbt.version=0.13.0. Also, db is a sub-module, but I only want to publish db/target/db-deploy.zip file to nexus, other folder under db should not be published. When publish is executed, nexus repository has javadoc, source, jar and their checksum. It looks fine, I just want to add some custom artifact, is it possible ?